# Ignorar pasta e classes com __autoload

Tags: php, autoload

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas no meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro de `app` tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a seguinte função nativa do `php` para dar *auto load* nas classes:

```
<?php

require_once '/app/config.php';

function __autoload($class_name) {

    $folders = array(
        'class',
    );

    foreach ($folders as $folders_files) {
        $path = ROOT . 'app' . SEPARATOR . $folders_files . SEPARATOR . $class_name . '.php';

        var_dump($path);

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require_once $path;
        } else {
            die('File not found: ' . $path);
        }
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como ignorar a pasta **twitteroauth** e as **classes** dentro dela. Será possível?

**UPDATE**

Tentei com `spl_autoload_register();` e obtenho o mesmo erro:

> File not found in: C:\wamp64\www\twitter-login\app\class\OAuthException.php

```
<?php
function autoload ($class_name) {
    $folders = array(
        'class',
    );

    foreach ($folders as $folders_files) {
        $path = ROOT . 'app' . SEPARATOR . $folders_files . SEPARATOR . $class_name . '.php';

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require_once $path;
        } else {
            die('File not found in: ' . $path);
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("autoload");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma, sem usar o `else` com `die` assim, ele irá ignorar e não irá mostrar erros. Apenas `exceptions` do próprio `wampserver`.

Obs: Irá mostrar erros se a classe não existir, faça o teste, insira no seu código, `$teste = new Teste;`.

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    $folders = array(
        'class'
    );

    foreach ($folders as $folders_files) {
        $path = ROOT . 'app' . SEPARATOR . $folders_files . SEPARATOR . $class . '.php';


        if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+$/', $class)) {
      if (file_exists($path)) {
          require $path;
          return true;
      }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Its very good, vlw men, funcionou aoksokaosk.

Comment: Disponha. Amigão